# Volume form under holomorphic automorphisms

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, measure-theory

$(M,\omega)$ is a compact Kaehler manifold and $f_{t,s}$ are 1-parameter group generated by holomorphic vector fields $V_s$. My question is whether the function $\frac{f_{t,s}^* \omega^n}{\omega^n}$ is a bounded independent of $t$ and $s$. If not, can we control the $L^p$($p>1$) norm of $\frac{f_{t,s}^* \omega^n}{\omega^n}$ uniformly with respect to $t$ and $s$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such bound.  As a counterexample take $(M,\omega)=(\mathbb{CP}^1, \omega_{FS})$.  Identify $\mathbb{CP}^1$ with $\mathbb{C}\cup \infty$; in such co-ordinates
$$\omega_{FS}=\frac{i dz\wedge d\overline z}{(1+|z|^2)^2}.$$
The radial vector field $V=z\partial/\partial z$ on $\mathbb{C}$ extends smoothly to a holo vector field on $\mathbb{CP}^1$, and the pullbacks of $\omega_{FS}$ by the family of diffeomorphisms generated by $V$ are
$$\omega_{\lambda}=\frac{i dz\wedge d\overline z}{(\lambda^{-1}+\lambda|z|^2)^2},$$
where $\lambda$ varies in $\mathbb{R}^+$.  The ratio
$$
\frac{\omega_\lambda}{\omega_1}=\frac{(1+|z|^2)^2}{(\lambda^{-1}+\lambda|z|^2)^2}
$$
is clearly unbounded.  The $L^p$ norm of this quantity is also unbounded ($p>1$), since for $\lambda$ large,
\begin{align*}
\int_\mathbb{C}\left[\frac{\omega_\lambda}{\omega_1}\right]^{2p}\omega_1
&=\int_\mathbb{C}\frac{(1+|z|^2)^{2p-2}}{(\lambda^{-1}+\lambda|z|^2)^{2p}}i dz\wedge d\overline z\\
&\geq\int_{|z|<\lambda^{-1}}\frac{(1+|z|^2)^{2p-2}}{(\lambda^{-1}+\lambda|z|^2)^{2p}}i dz\wedge d\overline z\\
&\geq\int_{|z|<\lambda^{-1}}\frac{i dz\wedge d\overline z}{(2\lambda^{-1})^{2p}}\\
&=C\lambda^{2p-2}.
\end{align*}
One remark:  I don't understand why there are two parameters $t$ and $s$ in your notation -- usually the notation for a 1-parameter subgroup features only one parameter!  Did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: thank you for your counterexample. In fact, I want to the uniform $L^p(p>1)$ bound of the rate for 1-parameter group generated by all holo vector fields, so $f_{t,s}$ is generated by $V_s$. Now, it seems wrong! Thank you so much!